# Follow only child links using Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy and I'm not sure how to tell it to only follow links that are subpages of the current url. For example, if you are here:

```
www.test.com/abc/def
```

then I want scrapy to follow:

```
www.test.com/abc/def/ghi
www.test.com/abc/def/jkl
www.test.com/abc/def/*
```

but not:

```
www.test.com/abc/*
www.test.com/*
```

or any other domain for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#basespider-example

Write a spider deriving on the BaseSpider. In basespider parse call back you need to return the requests which you need to follow through. Just make sure the the request you are generating is of the form you like. i.e. the extracted url from the response using is a child of the  current url( this will be response url). And make a request object and yield them.